# Mysql/Phpmyadmin hex ASCII/BINARY

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, hex

I am trying to transform a value that is in char(20) into hex varchar(40).

The value is

> _ÆúÛlw¦™‹Q|Ý­"9Õ

After i used hex on it it gave me 40char list

> **5FC386C3BAC39B6C77C2A6E284A2E280B9510C7C**

But from what i've researched the conversion was not good. The actual hex should've been

> *5FC6FADB6C77A6998B510C7CDD0419AD221A39D5*

Question is why the hex process didn't go as planned if all things were in place and used ?

I used phpmyadmin for this. And the command used was

```
UPDATE tablename SET col2name =hex(col1name);
```

col2name = varchar(40)

col1name = char(20)

p.s I've taken that first value to some decrypt site and used ASCII to HEX and it converted with the good value.

Answer (score 0):

I think the "ASCII to HEX" converter returned a different hex representation, because the input was specified to be in ASCII and not UTF-8.

The second character in the string   **Æ**
appears to be Latin Upper Case AE diphthong.

The UTF-8 encoding for that, displayed as HEX, is **`C386`**. Which is what the MySQL HEX function returned.

If the MySQL session is using **utf8** characterset, then it appears that the MySQL `HEX` function returned the string we would expect. (I only went as far as checking that second character.)

It looks like observed MySQL behavior is consistent with the documented specification.

---

The value is CHAR(20), but what *characterset* is that value in? From what we're seeing, it doesn't look like ASCII or extended ASCII.  It looks to be UTF-8.

---

References:

**The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)**

https://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

**What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text**

http://kunststube.net/encoding/

---

**FOLLOWUP**

```
SELECT HEX('_ÆúÛlw¦™‹Q|Ý­"9Õ') AS utf8
```

---

```
utf8                                                    
------------------------------------------------------
5FC386C3BAC39B6C77C2A6E284A2E280B9517CC39DC2AD2239C395
```

---

```
SELECT HEX(CONVERT('_ÆúÛlw¦™‹Q|Ý­"9Õ' USING latin1)) AS latin1
```

---

```
latin1                            
--------------------------------
5FC6FADB6C77A6998B517CDDAD2239D5
```

---

**utf8 encoding**

```
HEX('_')  HEX('Æ')  HEX('ú')  HEX('Û')  HEX('l')  HEX('w')  HEX('¦')  HEX('™')
--------  --------  -------- ---------  --------  --------  --------  --------  
5F        C386      C3BA      C39B      6C        77        C2A6      E284A2

HEX('‹')  HEX('Q')  HEX('|')  HEX('Ý')  HEX('­')   HEX('"')  HEX('9')  HEX('Õ')  
--------  --------  --------  --------  --------  --------  --------  ---------
E280B9    51        7C        C39D      C2AD      22        39        C395
```

**latin1 encoding**

```
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
5F C6 FA DB 6C 77 A6 99 8B 51 7C DD AD 22 39 D5
```

---

if we start with the hex representation that you say is "correct", and show the UTF8 encoding for that...

```
SELECT HEX(CONVERT(CONVERT(UNHEX('5FC6FADB6C77A6998B510C7CDD0419AD221A39D5') USING latin1) USING utf8))

-- ---- ---- ---- -- -- ---- ------ ------ -- -- -- ---- -- -- ---- -- -- -- ----
5F C386 C3BA C39B 6C 77 C2A6 E284A2 E280B9 51 0C 7C C39D 04 19 C2AD 22 1A 39 C395
                                              ^^         ^^ ^^         ^^
```

We see that the string contains *four* unprintable characters. And that encoding require 31 bytes, or 62 hex digits.

Comment: If i go to http://www.yellowpipe.com/yis/tools/encrypter/index.php and use ASCII to hex and input that code i receive the proper hex string that matches the hex into the files which needs to match the hex into the database.

That's why i said its ASCII because that site converted from ASCII to HEX.
Both cols are utf8. The char (20) is utf8_general_ci the varchar(40) is utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: I think the problem you are reporting happened before the HEX function... the HEX function is just revealing the problem. The MySQL `HEX` function is correctly converting a UTF-8 encoded value into a hex representation. Given the code points `U+005F U+00C6 U+00FA U+00DB`, a UTF-16 encoding would look like  `'0x 005F 00C6 00FA 00DB`'. An ASCII encoding would look like `'0x 5F C6 FA DB'`. And a UTF-8 encoding of those code points would look like `'0x 5F C386 C3BA C39B'`

Comment: and what should I do then ?

Comment: If you want to return a hex representation of an ASCII encoding, then you could do a characterset conversion, get the UTF-8 encoding converted to an ASCII encoding, and then get a hex representation of that, e.g. `SELECT HEX(CONVERT(col1name USING latin1))`. From all appearances, it seems like you aren't aware of the characterset conversions that are going on. If you don't get a handle on those, you are headed for a mojibake mess.

Comment: what i do after select hex? i get a bunch of numbers but none are the right values i need

Comment: i just notice on your FOLLOWUP that it gives a wrong value at latin1

Comment: I copy pasted the value displayed in the question, and to me it looks like it's 16 characters. That's 16 code points. Looks like the UTF8 encoding is 16 code points ... `5F C386 C3BA C39B 6C 77 C2A6 E284 A2E2 80B9 51 7CC3 9DC2 AD22 39 C395`.  in latin1 (one byte per character) that's going to be encoded in 16 bytes, 32 hex digits. And that's what is shown in the FOLLOWUP. I believe those 32 hex digits represent the correct encoding of those 16 characters in latin1.

Comment: There are some hidden (unprintable) characters in the utf8 encoding. The 40 hex digits for the utf8 encoding (in the question) shows only 12 characters, with a "hidden" `0x0C` for the 11th character.

Comment: it worked. everything is ok now. thank you for the support.